# Setting Chrome profile in Selenium doesn't bypass Microsoft MFA

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to incorporate scraping data from the AWS management console into an automation script, and for some reason my company's AWS is behind a Microsoft multi-factor authentication system. This isn't an issue when going to the console link manually, as the browser remembers that in the past I've already gone through the MFA process and I am directed right to the console. When navigating to the same link in Selenium I am instead brought to the MFA page asking my permission to text/call my phone.

I learned that this could be solved by setting Chrome Profile in the Webdriver options.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/")
```

Even after setting this I am still redirected to the MFA page every time. Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there an easy way to check if the Chrome Profile is actually working as expected?

Comment: Try to create a dedicated dir by running chrome with --user-data-dir="/tmp/dev-chrome", pass MFA and feed that to make sure it's not a permissions issue or an issue with the space in the path.

Comment: I also see that in Mac the path is "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default" so try to add Default at the end first

Comment: @Roeften Hey this has been the best feedback so far. Got my script to work for the short term, but the temp/dev-chrome profile reset when I restarted my computer. Not sure the difference between using this temp profile and pointing to an existing one (which after the restart still is past the MFA)

Comment: @Roeften Just some clarification...I had already tried putting default in the path, and also using the user_data path as someone responded below and no difference. The only thing that's got past the MFA so far is setting profile as --user-data-dir="/tmp/dev-chrome" and pass MFA one time. But this is annoying to do every time the computer is restarted

Comment: Use some persistent path, tmp usually not persistent.  E.g /Users/myuser/chromedev or /var/chomedev. I am not familiar with MacOs so I don't know if there is a permissions issue at play. Alternatively navigate to /Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/ and make sure you are using the correct profile name (case sensitive) listed in there

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an actual user data dir not just the folder where the general chrome data is stored.
For the default chrome profile the name would be:

```
"/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default"
```

Comment: Okay I gotchu, changed it and no difference. The only thing that's worked so far was running with profile: --user-data-dir="/tmp/dev-chrome", but this resets on computer restart.

Answer (score 0):

//Add argument and provide path to userdata
Remember to change username to your username.

Option.AddArgument("user-data-dir=c:\Users\~username~\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Userdata");

//Add whatever profile number that corresponds to session you want to open

Option.AddArgument("--profile-directory-Profile-10");

*Find profile by using chrome://version flag in session you want to use. The flag will tell you profile number.